# Can't login to samba secure share

Tags: 14.04, samba

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7 64 bit on my other PC.
I have created insecure shares and I can login to them so I followed these instructions to make a secure share: https://www.liberiangeek.net/2014/07/ubuntu-tips-create-samba-file-server-ubuntu-14-04/

```
davidn@hillman:/tank$ ls -la documents
total 22
drwxrwx---  2 davidn securedgroup  2 Oct 16 11:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root   root         13 Oct 17 16:13 ..
```

from /etc/smb.conf:

```
[documents]
 path = /tank/documents
 valid users = @securedgroup
 guest ok = no
 writable = yes
 browsable = yes
```

Here is the server tree:

```
davidn@hillman:/tank$ smbtree

WORKGROUP
        \\SRVR1                         Samba Server 4.1.6-Ubuntu
                \\SRVR1\IPC$            IPC Service (Samba Server 4.1.6-Ubuntu)
                \\SRVR1\documents
                \\SRVR1\tv_programs
```

I am in the right group too

```
davidn@hillman:/tank$ groups davidn
davidn : davidn adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare securedgroup
```

So I am in the right group, the directory ownership and permissions are correct and yet every time I try to login from windows it says I do not have access.
Any ideas why this might be please?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at a network trace when you use `security=share`, everyone is logged in as guest, so samba passwords don't really matter and the target directory must have permissions 0777. At least that has been my experience.